# Rendering Module Code to HTML

Tags: 7, theming

Semi-new to Drupal. I'm trying to find a way to render HTML inside my custom module.

Right now I'm using this method

```
$page = 'hello world';
return $page;
```

Which can get pretty dirty once you had some logic into it.

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe render it to some kind of template file and pass an array of vars?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: _"Maybe render it to some kind of template file and pass an array of vars?"_...yep, you've just described Drupal's theming system :) See [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)

Comment: ...or if you just need to wrap your code in some DIVs, just create the render array and Drupal will take care of the hard work.

Answer (score 0):

Clive is right that using the drupal theme system is your best bet if you're going to be doing significant variable manipulation but if you just want to load a big blob of HTML into your module you can do it a couple of ways in PHP.

For short blobs, try the EOF method

```
$str = <<<EOF
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>$world</p>
  ... etc.      
EOF;
```

For longer blobs, use file_get_contents()

```
$myhtml = file_get_contents(path_to_module().'/my_html.tpl');
```